# How use MeasureIt on objects in different layers orthogonally

Tags: measurement

I want to use the MeasureIt plugin in Blender to make orthogonal measurements on my technical drawing (blueprint). So the measurements between objects (in different layers!) need to be constrained on the X, Y or Z axis.

I've only managed to make a measurement between two vertices of two different objects in different layers in an absolute way: the measurement then takes the shortest route between two vertices. So you get a diagonal measurement and I want it constrained to one of the three axis (please see pic below, measurement '234' should be constrained on the horizontal axis).

Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

Best regards,

Rob

[image: none constrained measurement via MeasureIt plugin]